# Celery task updates

Tags: django, celery

I'm investigating the capabilities of celery in regards of longer running tasks, where the user wants to observe the progress. The application is based on Django, the tasks are started via RPC and involve synchronizing a database with files on the file system.

From within the task I want to log on several levels (WARN, ERROR, INFO, ...) and I also want the user to filter messages according to the loglevel, so I guess logging to my database would be feasible.

My questions are:

- Is it recommended to log into the same database my Django application is using?
- How do I set up celery to log into the database using Pythons standard logging module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just update the task with the current status and query using the task id.  Then you are transparently using what ever backend you have configured rather than overloading your database.

Ask explains the technique [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/celery-users/ZOAj7FzZqeI).

```
YourTaskObject(Task):
    run(self, **kwargs):
        while true:
            # do some work
            self.backend.store_result(self.request.id, result={"percent_done": number}, status="PROGRESS")
```

Then you just use AsyncTask result:

```
result = YourTaskObject.AsyncResult(task_id=task_id)
if not result.ready():
    progress = result.result.percent_done
else:
    ...
```

Comment: Your approach is definitely interesting, as it does not involve any database/files apart from the backend it requires anyways. I will further investigate it.

Comment: It uses whatever backend you have configured.  That could be your database or it could be rabbitmq or redis or mongodb.